Complexity of strong graph realization problem
Given a simple graph $G$, let $k^{th}$ degree of a vertex $v_i\in G$ denote the number of vertices that have distance $k$ from $v$. Notice that first degree is equivalent to degree by standard definitions.
Then let extended degree matrix $M$ be a matrix where element $m_{i, j}$ is equal to $j^{th}$ degree of vertex $v_i\in G$. Rows that contain only zeros can be omitted from the matrix.
For example, given a 4-cycle we have:
$$
M = \begin{matrix}
2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{matrix}
$$
Because for every vertex there exist two adjacent vertices, and one vertex with distance $2$.
Now, suppose, we are given an arbitrary matrix as an input. If there exists at least one graph whose extended degree matrix is equivalent to the input, then that matrix is valid. How hard is it to decide that the given matrix is valid?
For example, $\begin{matrix}2 & 2 & 1 & 1\end{matrix}$ is not a valid matrix because the first two vertices must belong to a component of 3 vertices and the last two vertices must belong to a component of 2 vertices. This requires 5 vertices, but there are 4 in total.
